# C/C++ returning struct by value under the hood

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86-64, win64

(This question is specific to my machine's architecture and calling conventions, Windows x86_64)

I don't exactly remember where I had read this, or if I had recalled it correctly, but I had heard that, when a function should return some struct or object by value, it will either stuff it in `rax` (if the object can fit in the register width of 64 bits) or be passed a pointer to where the resulting object would be (I'm guessing allocated in the calling function's stack frame) in `rcx`, where it would do all the usual initialization, and then a `mov rax, rcx` for the return trip. That is, something like

```
extern some_struct create_it(); // implemented in assembly
```

would really have a secret parameter like

```
extern some_struct create_it(some_struct* secret_param_pointing_to_where_i_will_be);
```

Did my memory serve me right, or am I incorrect? How are large objects (i.e. wider than the register width) returned by value from functions?

Comment: You omitted a return type from your example function, when you want information about what is returned.

Comment: It seems like you're talking about [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which is C++ specific. I'm unaware of any such feature in C.

Comment: It really depends on the C++ compiler, and on the level of optimizations that you are using for your build.  There are many C++ compilers out there for x86-64 win64.

Comment: @mike: no, it is defined by the platform ABI. If it were allowed to vary between optimization levels, you wouldn't be able to use external libraries. If it could vary between compilers, you'd need different libraries for each compiler. This is why calling conventions must be defined for each platform, and hence why platform ABIs exist.

Comment: Yes.  Doesn't just apply to the return value, also the parameters.  The exact details are quite convoluted and poorly documented.  Agner Fog did the hard work, [chapter 7](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) has every you'd want to know and more.

Comment: @rici ok, thanks.  I stand corrected.  (Funny thing is, I have read the ABI.  I just did not remember that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple disassembling of a code exampling what you're saying

```
typedef struct 
{
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    char x;
} A;

A foo(int b, int c)
{
    A myA = {b, c, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
    return myA; 
}

int main()
{   
    A myA = foo(5,9);   
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the disassembly of the foo function, and the main function calling it

**main:**

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub     esp, 30h
call    ___main
lea     eax, [esp+20]        ; placing the addr of myA in eax
mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 9 ; param passing 
mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 5 ; param passing
mov     [esp], eax           ; passing myA addr as a param
call    _foo
mov     eax, 0
leave
retn
```

**foo:**

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 20h
mov     eax, [ebp+12]  
mov     [ebp-28], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+16]
mov     [ebp-24], eax
mov     dword ptr [ebp-20], 5
mov     dword ptr [ebp-16], 6
mov     dword ptr [ebp-12], 7
mov     dword ptr [ebp-8], 9
mov     byte ptr [ebp-4], 0Ah
mov     eax, [ebp+8]
mov     edx, [ebp-28]
mov     [eax], edx     
mov     edx, [ebp-24]
mov     [eax+4], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-20]
mov     [eax+8], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-16]
mov     [eax+0Ch], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-12]
mov     [eax+10h], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-8]
mov     [eax+14h], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-4]
mov     [eax+18h], edx
mov     eax, [ebp+8]
leave
retn
```

now let's go through what just happened, so when calling foo the paramaters were passed in the following way, 9 was at highest address, then 5 then the address the myA in main begins

```
lea     eax, [esp+20]        ; placing the addr of myA in eax
mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 9 ; param passing 
mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 5 ; param passing
mov     [esp], eax           ; passing myA addr as a param
```

within `foo` there is some local `myA` which is stored on the stack frame, since the stack is going downwards, the lowest address of `myA` begins in `[ebp - 28]`, the -28 offset could be caused by struct alignments so I'm guessing the size of the struct should be 28 bytes here and not 25 as expected. and as we can see in `foo` after the local `myA` of `foo` was created and filled with parameters and immediate values, it is copied and re-written to the address of `myA` passed from `main` ( this is the actual meaning of return by value )

```
mov     eax, [ebp+8]
mov     edx, [ebp-28]
```

`[ebp + 8]` is where the address of `main::myA` was stored ( memory address go upwards hence ebp + old ebp ( 4 bytes ) + return address ( 4 bytes )) at overall ebp + 8 to get to the first byte of `main::myA`, as said earlier `foo::myA` is stored within `[ebp-28]` as stack goes downwards

```
mov     [eax], edx
```

place `foo::myA.b` in the address of the first data member of `main::myA` which is `main::myA.b`

```
mov     edx, [ebp-24]
mov     [eax+4], edx
```

place the value that resides in the address of `foo::myA.c` in edx, and place that value within the address of `main::myA.b`  + 4 bytes which is `main::myA.c`

as you can see this process repeats itself through out the function

```
mov     edx, [ebp-20]
mov     [eax+8], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-16]
mov     [eax+0Ch], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-12]
mov     [eax+10h], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-8]
mov     [eax+14h], edx
mov     edx, [ebp-4]
mov     [eax+18h], edx
mov     eax, [ebp+8]
```

which basically proves that when returning a struct by val, that could not be placed in as a param, what happens is that the address of where the return value should reside in is passed as a param to the function and within the function being called the values of the returned struct are copied into the address passed as a parameter...

hope this exampled helped you visualize what happens under the hood a little bit better :)

**EDIT**

I hope that you've noticed that my example was using 32 bit assembler and **I KNOW** you've asked regarding x86-64, but I'm currently unable to disassemble code on a 64 bit machine so I hope you take my word on it that the concept is exactly the same both for 64 bit and 32 bit, and that the calling convention is nearly the same

Comment: Use http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to look at compiler output for x86, x86-64, ARM, MIPS, PowerPC, or AVR, with clang or gcc.  Also, you could shorten the example by using `A myA = { b, c, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`.  And probably drop a couple struct members to shorten the asm.  As long at it's larger than 128 bits, the x86-64 SysV calling convention won't pack it into RDX:RAX.

Comment: Also, the asm would be a lot easier to read if you compiled `foo` with optimization enabled.  Having it store to a local on the stack and then copy that to the return value pointer is really noisy and hard to follow if you don't already know that's what it's doing.

Comment: Originally this code did a little bit more complicated as part of me testing the disassembly of it, I've quickly edited it without changing that, but you're right though it's much more readable, wouldn't do that in actual code developing :), and I agree with you, I just wanted to prove that the actual copying is what goes on under the hood @PeterCordes

Answer (score 5):

That is exactly correct. The caller passes an extra argument which is the address of the return value. Normally it will be on the caller's stack frame but there are no guarantees.

The precise mechanics are specified by the platform ABI, but this mechanism is very common.

Various commentators have left useful links with documentation for calling conventions, so I'll hoist some of them into this answer:

- Wikipedia article on [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)
- Agner Fog's collection of optimization resources, including a [summary of calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manual_call_conv) (Direct link to [57-page PDF document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manual_call_conv).)
- Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) documentation on [calling conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx).
- StackOverflow [x86](/questions/tagged/x86)  [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has lots of useful links.

Comment: more specifically, see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to ABI docs that specify the rules for when a struct is packed into one or two registers, or when a pointer is passed as a hidden first-arg.  The rules differ between ABIs, for 32 and 64 bit.  See also [structs in calling conventions on SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions/12659/32-bit-cdecl-dealing-with-structs)